# Is there a good way to know if a method was called by a parent or from elsewhere?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following code where the goal is that when a method is called on a parent it then calls the same method on all of it's children, this is then where the actual work is done.

```
public class Parent {

    Child[] children;

    public doWork() {
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) //For all my children
            children.get(i).dowork();            //Call the same method
        Log.ReportWorkBeingDone(this);           //Report this has happened
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{

    @override
    public doWork() {
        //Actual Work                            //Run the actual code
        Log.ReportWorkBeingDone(this);           //Report this has happened
    }
}
```

Right now when the `doWork()` is called on the parent the `Log` class gets a method call from the `Parent` and then once from each of the `Child` objects in it's array.

Is there a programming pattern or just a good way of only running the call to the `Log` class once? So if `doWork()` is called on a Child from outside this chain of classes then the child will call the `Log` method but if `doWork()` is called on the parent only the parent will call the `Log` method and the children won't?

---

All I can think of is having something like this:

```
public class Parent {

    Child[] children;

    public doWork() {
        sneakyHiddenWork();
        Log.ReportWorkBeingDone(this);                     //Report this has happened
    }

    protected sneakyHiddenWork(){
        for(int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)           //For all my children
            children.get(i).sneakyHiddenWork();            //Call the same method
    }

}

public class Child extends Parent{

    @override
    protected sneakyHiddenWork() {
        //Actual Work                                      //Run the actual code
    }
}
```

Comment: It is good as you wrote. I will just use name `doWork` and `doWorkAndLog`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can be done with AspectJ, but I doubt that it's worth introducing new dependencies just for that.

Comment: An alternative is to pass a `boolean isParent` into `doWork` and only do the logging if it's true.

Comment: Checked LoggerFactory [https://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html ]?

Comment: Ditto you could new an Exception (but not throw it) and call its getStackTrace and inspect the output, but that's expensive. Agree this is OK as is, but pick a better name. If your logging function accepts `this` (and calls its getClass?) you may not even need to override doWork in the child. Also consider if you should log before or after you do the work. You could also use the Java 'for each', i.e. `for (Parent p : children) { p.sneakyHiddenWork(); }` rather than index and get.

Comment: Yeah I just threw names in for now and to be clear :) Also just realised I don't need the public overridden method in the `Child` do I... It's exactly the same as the one in the `Parent`.

Comment: The technique whereby code behaves differently depending on who called it is called 'state orientation', and was identified as poor practice in the 1960s. Find a better design.

Comment: Interesting.  I knew it was poor practice, but didn't realize there was a name for it.

Comment: There is no good way of doing this, because a method should not care where it is called from. You have a code smell, or an XY Problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution (`sneakyHiddenWork`) is the best solution ... though your choice of names is missing the point.  (It is not "sneaky".  It is a common pattern to do this kind of thing.)

Yes, it is possible to find out what the name of the calling method is, but this is not well-supported in Java<sup>1</sup>, and the procedure is **expensive**.  You instantiate an exception object, and then look at the exception's captured stack frames returned by `Throwable::getStackTrace`.  (That's what logger frameworks like log4j do under the covers ...)

See also: [Accessing caller information quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246227/accessing-caller-information-quickly)<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1 - There is no specific "get the name of my caller" method.  Furthermore, the method that I described is actually non-portable since it permitted for `Throwable::getStackTrace` to return an empty array of frames.</sup>

<sup>2 - The top answer alludes to a couple of non-portable alternatives.  The Java 9 version using the `StackWalker` API is promising, but it will still be relatively expensive because `StackWalker` needs to snapshot the stack frames.</sup>